# Test after_create_commit callback using `shoulda-callback-matchers` gem + rails 5 + rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, callback, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using `shoulda-callback-matchers` gem to test the callback. Rails version is 5.2.2 and RSpec version is 3.8.0.

Anyone know how to test `after_create_commit` callback using `shoulda-callback-matchers` gem?

It is working for `after_create` and `after_update`.

**model code**

```rb
after_create :admission_created_notification
after_update :admission_status_change_notification
```

**sample example**

```rb
context "callbacks" do
 let(:admission) { create(:admission) }
   it { expect(admission).to callback(:admission_created_notification).after(:create) }
   it { expect(admission).to callback(:admission_status_change_notification).after(:update) }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Didn't use the above mentioned gem. I use the default way of Rspec to write rspec for these callback.
**Model callback code**

```
class Admission < ApplicationRecord
  after_create_commit :admission_created_notification
  after_update_commit :admission_status_change_notification
end
```

**Model Spec Code**

```
context 'create and update' do
    let(:student_detail) { FactoryBot.create(:student_detail) }
    let(:institute_program) { FactoryBot.create(:institute_program) }
    let(:admission) { FactoryBot.create(:admission, student_detail: student_detail, institute_program: institute_program) }
    it 'When create' do
      admission.student_detail.notifications.count(1)
      admission.institute_program.institute_detail.notifications.count(1)
    end
    it 'When applied' do
      admission.update(status: 'applied')
      admission.student_detail.notifications.count(2)
      admission.institute_program.institute_detail.notifications.count(2)
    end
    it 'When accepted' do
      admission.update(status: 'accepted')
      admission.student_detail.notifications.count(3)
      admission.institute_program.institute_detail.notifications.count(3)
    end
    it 'When rejected' do
      admission.update(status: 'rejected')
      admission.student_detail.notifications.count(3)
    end
    it 'When approved' do
      admission.update(status: 'approved')
      admission.student_detail.notifications.count(4)
      admission.institute_program.institute_detail.notifications.count(4)
      admission.notifications.count(9)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
RSpec.describe YourModel, type: :model do
  context 'callbacks check' do
    it { is_expected.to callback(:admission_created_notification).after(:create) }
    it { is_expected.to callback(:admission_status_change_notification).after(:update) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks but you posted the same code as I written. You just mentioned below line
`RSpec.describe YourModel, type: :model do` 
which is default syntax of rspec model spec.

Comment: @wish, please clarify your question

Comment: I found the solution and I posted the answer as well. Thank for showing interest.